# Google map result blank screen with google logo on bottom

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio

I'm developing an Android app with Android Studio using Google Maps. I've generated the API_KEY and I followed every tutorial I've found but the blank screen still shows up.

This is the manifest file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.star.storesriders"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0"
android:sharedUserLabel="@id/login">
<uses-sdk 
      android:minSdkVersion="12"
      android:targetSdkVersion="15"
      android:maxSdkVersion="4"
/>
<permission
    android:name="com.star.storesriders.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-feature
   android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
   android:required="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.star.storesriders.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:debuggable="true"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedDebugMode"
    >

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="My API Key"/>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <activity
        android:name="MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".Geolocal" android:label="ClientMap" android:theme="@string/AppTheme"/>

    <activity android:name="com.star.storesriders.Menu_agent" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/AppTheme"/>


</application>
```

This is the XML layout file:

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<fragment
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
     />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is what shows up in logcat:

```
    05-06 10:34:47.511    1760-1760/com.star.storesriders W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa61c6908)
05-06 10:34:47.515    1760-1760/com.star.storesriders E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=market://details?id=com.google.android.gms flg=0x80000 pkg=com.android.vending }
            at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1622)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1417)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3370)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3331)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3566)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3534)
            at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza$5.onClick(Unknown Source)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-06 10:34:47.515      127-206/? W/genymotion_audio﹕ out_write() limiting sleep time 44149 to 23219
05-06 10:34:47.523      299-582/system_process W/ActivityManager﹕ Force finishing activity com.star.storesriders/.Geolocal
05-06 10:34:47.539      127-206/? W/genymotion_audio﹕ out_write() limiting sleep time 55759 to 23219
05-06 10:34:47.567      127-206/? W/genymotion_audio﹕ out_write() limiting sleep time 47369 to 23219
05-06 10:34:47.591      127-206/? W/genymotion_audio﹕ out_write() limiting sleep time 28979 to 23219
05-06 10:34:47.691      299-582/system_process D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 207K, 25% free 7527K/9920K, paused 15ms, total 16ms
05-06 10:34:48.203      299-317/system_process W/ActivityManager﹕ Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{533ee154 u0 com.star.storesriders/.Geolocal}
05-06 10:34:49.071      127-206/? W/genymotion_audio﹕ out_write() limiting sleep time 30678 to 23219
05-06 10:34:49.751    1760-1760/com.star.storesriders I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 1760 SIG: 9
05-06 10:34:50.151      299-792/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ Process com.star.storesriders (pid 1760) has died.
05-06 10:34:50.155      299-468/system_process I/qtaguid﹕ Failed write_ctrl(s 0 10051) res=-1 errno=1
05-06 10:34:50.155      299-468/system_process W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger﹕ setKernelCountSet(10051, 0) failed with errno -1
05-06 10:34:50.159      299-310/system_process I/WindowState﹕ WIN DEATH: Window{5344e750 u0 com.star.storesriders/com.star.storesriders.Connexion}
05-06 10:34:50.183     299-1151/system_process I/WindowState﹕ WIN DEATH: Window{5346ac60 u0 com.star.storesriders/com.star.storesriders.Fiche_client}
05-06 10:34:50.187      299-299/system_process I/WindowState﹕ WIN DEATH: Window{5347c784 u0 com.star.storesriders/com.star.storesriders.Menu_agent}
05-06 10:34:50.191      299-756/system_process I/WindowState﹕ WIN DEATH: Window{5341becc u0 com.star.storesriders/com.star.storesriders.AllClient}
05-06 10:34:50.195      299-312/system_process I/WindowState﹕ WIN DEATH: Window{5348180c u0 com.star.storesriders/com.star.storesriders.Geolocal}
05-06 10:34:50.327    1818-1818/? D/dalvikvm﹕ Late-enabling CheckJNI
05-06 10:34:50.355      299-792/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ Start proc com.star.storesriders for activity com.star.storesriders/.Fiche_client: pid=1818 uid=10051 gids={50051, 1015, 3003, 1006, 1028}
05-06 10:34:50.635      299-468/system_process I/qtaguid﹕ Failed write_ctrl(s 1 10051) res=-1 errno=1
05-06 10:34:50.635      299-468/system_process W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger﹕ setKernelCountSet(10051, 1) failed with errno -1
05-06 10:34:50.767    1818-1818/com.star.storesriders D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 45K, 13% free 4022K/4580K, paused 10ms, total 11ms
05-06 10:34:50.787    1818-1818/com.star.storesriders I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 4.979MB for 580956-byte allocation
05-06 10:34:50.799    1818-1827/com.star.storesriders D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 11% free 4589K/5148K, paused 13ms, total 13ms
05-06 10:34:50.819    1818-1820/com.star.storesriders D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 11% free 4589K/5148K, paused 4ms+0ms, total 7ms
05-06 10:34:50.951    1818-1818/com.star.storesriders D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_genymotion.so
05-06 10:34:50.967    1818-1818/com.star.storesriders D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb88d5f10, tid 1818
05-06 10:34:50.983    1818-1818/com.star.storesriders D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_genymotion.so
05-06 10:34:50.987    1818-1818/com.star.storesriders D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_genymotion.so
05-06 10:34:51.071    1818-1818/com.star.storesriders W/EGL_genymotion﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
05-06 10:34:51.115    1818-1818/com.star.storesriders D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
05-06 10:34:51.119      299-312/system_process W/InputMethodManagerService﹕ Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 1760 uid 10051
05-06 10:34:51.647      299-319/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ Displayed com.star.storesriders/.Fiche_client: +1s466ms
05-06 10:36:48.887        57-57/? W/Genyd﹕ Can't parse request
05-06 10:36:48.891        57-57/? D/Genyd﹕ Received Set Clipboard
05-06 10:36:48.891        57-57/? D/Genymotion﹕ Received Set Clipboard
```

Comment: share your logcat?? I think this is your API_KEY issue.

Comment: It seems that is something wrong with your api_key. Did you share with google the correct fingerprint of the keyring? Please, share your logcat, it could be helpfully

Comment: Agree with Sajal...it might be API key issue. Let us know the process you generated it.

Comment: i'm running my app on device

Comment: it would be more helpful if you add logcat in your question above then in comment

Comment: Check time on your device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solved this bug, it was very dump of me but i was generating the API-Key with debug-keystore while i signed my application with an other keystore to build on a device. The API-Key is bind to a keystore and must be changed it was a misstake with the SHA1 so with the API KEY. this what i put in command to get it
keytool -list -v -keystore "C:\USERS\pika.android(myappkey).jks" -alias keyname -storepass passwordalias -keypass password

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no playstore and google paly services on your device, test on another device which have these.

Comment: no i'm sure about that i've installed them myself, i'm running it on a Galaxy tablet

Comment: <permission
    android:name="com.star.storesriders.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" /> put "permission" before MAPS_RECEIVE in above line.

Comment: xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" put this line in your layout.xml after first line of your XML file.

Comment: i put the last one in my layout then when i try to run my app an error come up because of it

Comment: Error:(3) Error parsing XML: XML declaration not well-formed

Comment: <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<fragment
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
     />
</RelativeLayout> copy this code and replace your xml with this code

Comment: what should this error means : android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=market://details?id=com.google.android.gms flg=0x80000 pkg=com.android.vending }

Comment: it means that there is some problem with your playstore or google play services. test your app on another device make sure internet should on.

Comment: what about this error : Could not find class 'android.app.AppOpsManager', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zza

Comment: Did you check your app on another device.

Comment: no i don't have an available one at this time i will try it later although i'm almost sure that the problem it's not with the device